# How to display error message on the same page even with attachment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

I have been trying to figure this out for days with no luck. I am working on Sharepoint 2013 application. In my application, the fields will be validated and display the error if the input is wrong. Just like the picture below:
[image]

However, when I attach any document, the error is NOT displayed on the same page. Instead it will direct to a new page:

[image]

This only happens when there is attachment.

My code which is called by ItemAdding() is below:

```
private bool ShowError(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        if (errorMsg.Length > 0)
        {
            string temp = errorMsg.ToString().Replace("\r\n", " | ");

            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
            properties.ErrorMessage = temp;

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Please advise. I want the error to be displayed on the same page just like without attachment.

Comment: Can you try by adding  properties.Cancel = true;